# show an image and link it to a sound

Tags: ios, image, audio, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to make a simple app for some kids. I want to show a photo and to link that photo to a sound.

When the kid click on "Play Sound" it should play an audio that represents the image.

so far I've done only showing the images, that I've put in Assets.xcassets, but my question is..
How can I link those photos to some audio files and play them by clicking on "Play Sound"

Here is my code in ViewController.swift :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var viewImage: UIImageView!
var images: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "photo1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo2.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo3.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo4.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo5.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo6.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo7.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "photo8.png")!
]
var currentImagesIndex = 0

@IBAction func nextImage(_ sender: Any) {
    currentImagesIndex += 1
    let numberOfImages = images.count
    let nextImagesIndex = currentImagesIndex % numberOfImages

    viewImage.image = images[nextImagesIndex]

}
```

So far, when I click on Next Photo it shows me a new photo, and it's working ok. All I want to do for now, it's to link the "photo1-8" to an audio and play it.

I'll appreciate any kind of help, 
Radu

Comment: add UITapGestureRecognizer on imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first add all your sound files to your project. I assume you know how to do this. After adding the files, your project navigator should look a bit like this:

[image]

For convenience, I will call your 8 sound files `sound1.mp3`, `sound2.mp3`, `sound3.mp3` ... `sound8.mp3`.

Create a property in the class called `soundFiles`:

```
let soundFiles: [String] = [
    "sound1",
    "sound2",
    "sound3",
    "sound4",
    "sound5",
    "sound6",
    "sound7",
    "sound8"
]
```

Also create a property called `player` to play the sounds:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
```

In the `@IBAction` of the "Play Sound" button, get the file path of the sound file and initialise the player:

```
let numberOfImages = images.count
let nextImagesIndex = currentImagesIndex % numberOfImages
let soundFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFiles[nextImagesIndex], withExtension: ".mp3")!
player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFilePath)
```

Then you can play the sound by calling `prepareToPlay()` and `play()` consecutively:

```
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()
```

Comment: hello and thanks for helping me. I have a little error.. When I try to run the app, it shows this error: "use of unresolved identifier 'nextImageIndex'. How can I fix it? sorry :)

Comment: @RaduRaducu oops! I meant `currentImageIndex`. You also seem to lack a good understanding of why these errors occur. I suggest you to learn more about swift first.

Comment: I know i have a lot of lacks.. but i'm trying my best to learn :). Sorri for bothering you. After fixing that "currentImageIndex" issue, now I have another one..and i really can't figure it out how to solve it. After clicking 8 times "next button" in app.. it crashes with the following message in console: "fatal error: index out of range". I've tried to return but with 0 results :)...  After crash, I Run the app again..and at the first time I click Next button... it crashes and sends me to "viewImage.image = image[nextImageIndex]".. thanks

Comment: @RaduRaducu Okay, I didn't read your code carefully. `currentImageIndex` will go out of bounds. See the edited answer that uses `nextImageIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import AV Foundation by adding this line in top: `import AVFoundation`
2. Drag **MP3, WAV** file in main project directory
3. Check "**Copy items if needed**" & App Name in "**Add to Targets**"
4. Use this code to play sound

   ```
   func playSound() {

    var btnSound: AVAudioPlayer!

    if let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fileName", withExtension: ".wav") {
       do{
           try btnSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL)
           btnSound.prepareToPlay()
           btnSound.play()
       } catch let err as NSError {
           print(err.debugDescription)
       }
    }

   }

   //call playSound function inside nextImage method
   ```

Tested with **Swift 3.1** in **xCode 8.3.2**

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I've tried your code, but I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'btn Sound'.